# How to arrive rank for the attached data set in SQL using the Date Column for the customers list shown

Tags: sql, grouping, rank

Friends i want to do rank function for the below set of records considering the maxium Last_transactiondate and assigning it as rank 1 now once i get that i will put No 1 ranks customer has Parent and remaining rank as Childs.

But due to different customerno and different values in other columns i am unable to do effective ranking. kindly help me in this part

I want to rank customers based on LastTransactionDate. consider the LastTransactionDate column, the value '14-06-2019 14:48:24' has the highest record or max date Hence the corresponding CustomerNo should be picked has Parent and rest should be tagged as child. If only if i could rank CustomerNo 0003178419452479 as rank 1 and then subsequent ranks in the descending order  which i am unable to do.  I cannot find Column not derive a column which exist with same value for all customers to put rank based on the Date column.

The code i have written and the output is shown here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5dR4.jpg)
[image]

Also the output Image shown here is the required output want from the above data set image

[image]

code

```html
> SELECT CustomerNO,CustomerID,CustomerIDType,CustomerNationalityCode,CustomerDateOfBirth,LastTransactionDate,Class_Profile,
,Dense_Rank() over ( PARTITION BY  n.CustomerNO ORDER BY LastTransactionDate DESC ) AS ranks, 
case when ranks=1 then 'P' else 'C' end as Class_Profile
FROM CustomerTabledetails
GROUP BY  CustomerNo,CustomerID,CustomerIDType,
CustomerNationalityCode,CustomerDateOfBirth,LastTransactionDate,Class_Profile
order by lasttransactiondate desc
```

Comment: Sql Code for the sample attached.

Comment: . . Your question can be improved.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* or DDL in the question help.  An appropriate database tag helps.  A clear explanation of what you want helps.  "Cluster analysis" is not very meaningful.

Comment: Attached sample data image and output desired in image, also shared the code. thanks

Comment: Is there an SQL function to read images? No, there is no such thing.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: edited the query with small code . Described the problem and required output wanted.